# How to access data in tuples in a datatype list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this list of tuples:

```
(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG'), (u'lastname', u'ZXYVUW')]
```

How do I access the data using the key for example firstname in the tuple?

Answer (score 3):

You can index as suggested with `l[0][0]` for the first element of the first tuple `[1][0]` for the first element of the second tuple etc.. but maybe creating  a dict would be a better approach if you know the keys you want to use:

```
 l = [(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG'), (u'lastname', u'ZXYVUW')]

 data = dict(l)

 print(data["firstname"])
 print(data["lastname"])
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFG
ZXYVUW
```

Answer (score 2):

Double subscript:

```
In [29]:
[(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG'), (u'lastname', u'ZXYVUW')][0][0]

Out[29]:
'firstname'
```

So the first index value returns the first element which is your tuple:

```
In [30]:
[(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG'), (u'lastname', u'ZXYVUW')][0]

Out[30]:
('firstname', 'ABCDEFG')
```

You then access the first element of the tuple pair by subscripting again as shown in first snippet

If you want to search your list of tuples you can use a list comprehension:

```
In [32]:
l = [(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG'), (u'lastname', u'ZXYVUW')]
[item for item in l if item[0] == 'firstname']

Out[32]:
[('firstname', 'ABCDEFG')]
```

The above assumes that the first element of the tuple is your key

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the index.

```
l = [(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG'), (u'lastname', u'ZXYVUW')]
print l[0][0]
```

first `[0]` refers the first element in the list (ie, first tuple) and the second `[0]` refers the first element in the first tuple.

Comment: @PM2Ring i'll delete those.

Answer (score 1):

```
[(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG'), (u'lastname', u'ZXYVUW')][0][0]
u'firstname'
```

You could use `double indexing` don't know it's correct name

**Single index would give:**

```
[(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG'), (u'lastname', u'ZXYVUW')][0]
(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG')
```

**In that you want first data:**

```
(u'firstname', u'ABCDEFG')[0]
u'firstname'
```